# Proper syntax for wp_register_style?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a cache-buster version to my CSS file.

The documents say:
`<?php wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); ?>`

But I have Googled and searched SO for the way these variables should be formatted.

I am trying

```
 wp_register_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', true, 1.5 );
```

But this is always 1.5, as in:
`/wp-content/themes/ofm_1.5/style.css?ver=1.5'`

How do I have it increment when the css has been edited?

Comment: Interestingly enough if you pass 1.6 as the 4th ($ver = version) parameter, it'll be 1.6

Comment: I realize that, I was looking for a way to increment it automatically.

Comment: so go for Brandt's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to increment the version value in your `wp_enqueue_style` call

ie:

```
wp_register_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', true, 1.5.1 );
```

One thing I like to do, is use the `filemtime` as a version:

```
$ourFile_version = filemtime(dirname(__FILE__). "/style.css");
wp_register_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', true, $ourFile_version );
```

As another member pointed out - the last argument (`1.5` in your case) is the version number.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Thanks, just the idea I was looking for.  Works fine, but I'm curious how does the `dirname(__FILE__)` know which file to evaluate?

Comment: `__FILE__` is a "magic variable" which basically means "the file currently being interpolated" - so if you had that in an included file (like functions.php), it would refer to that file. So what this does is, the file that your `wp_enqueue_script` call resides in, uses that file as a reference point, then gets that file's directory (in this case, our theme/child theme) and then appends your style.css to the dir path and feeds that path to the `filemtime`-which looks @ the file's (style.css) last mod timestamp,so if you used `__FILE__` in your `header.php` theme file, then header.php is reff'd